# tensorflow import problem although tensorflow is installed using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

Hi I am new to tensorflow running pything 3.6 and installed tensorflow using pip. I have encountered a problem where when I import it in python it gives me an error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Usman Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Usman Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Usman Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\Usman Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I researched and found solution that it might be Visual C++ Reditributable needs to be installed but I have installed it restarted but still same error. Any solution to this problem.

Comment: follow the tensorflow instructions maybe https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

Comment: Need more information regarding your question, such as are you using the cpu or gpu version? what have you installed prior to this? did you follow any guides?